# How can I design this class to support mocking?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to write unit tests with MOQ and I'm receiving this error message.

> Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.Name

This makes sense since Name is defined in the `IResource` interface and I specified Resource in the mock setup.

`ResourceGroupProperties` does not belong to an interface. I was trying to design this will multiple interfaces instead of one huge one since not all Azure Resources have a location or tags.

Should I create a `IResourceGroup` interface and that defines the members not in one of the other 3 interfaces and then inherit from the 3 interfaces? Or I'm I over doing it with all the interfaces?

```
// Mock setup
var mockResourceGroup = new Mock<ResourceGroup>();
mockResourceGroup.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns(name);
mockResourceGroup.Setup(x => x.Properties.ProvisioningState).Returns("Provisioned");

// ResourceGroup class
public class ResourceGroup : IResource, IResourceTags, IResourceLocation
{
    public string Etag { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ResourceGroupProperties Properties { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Tags { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As the exception message says you need to mark your `Name` to property either to `abstract` or `virtual` to be able to mock it.

Comment: BTW you should mock the interface the not the actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The class ResourceGroup has no functionality, just properties and no reason to use Moq. The following code is what I needed.

```
var mockResourceGroup = new ResourceGroup
                     {
                         Name = name,
                         Properties =
                             new ResourceGroupProperties
                             {
                                 ProvisioningState = "Provisioned"
                             }
                     };
```

Comment: This is not a mock this is just a dummy object. And the end of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69354229/count-number-of-times-a-recursive-method-is-called-using-moq/69358439#69358439) you can read more about the differences.